# Custom block template PHP page, possible to make content editable in UI?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, hooks

I have custom PHP files for a few blocks, e.g., */sites/all/themes/at-commerce/templates/block--block-10.tpl.php*

Is it possible to make this content editable using the block editing UI mechanism in Drupal administration, so the customer can make changes him/herself?

For example, customer visits URL *admin/structure/block/manage/block/10/configure* and can edit the content.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is already in Drupal 7 core. It's called the **Contextual Links** module. When enabled, modules can define menu paths that enable a set of links that is contextually relevant to the content.

In your case, a user with *Use contextual links* & *Administer block* permissions will see a gear icon that produces a dropdown link from where they can configure & edit content of any custom block.

[image: Contextual Block Link]